# How to push controller from ExtensionDelegate WatchKit

Tags: ios, controller, push, watchkit, watchos-2

I've got watch connectivity setup in the Extension Delegate of my watch app and I'd like to push a controller when a certain method is called. However `pushControllerWithName:context:` can't be called on the extension delegate.

Is there a way I could push a controller from the Extension Delegate?

Thanks a million

Comment: You can get a reference to your root interface controller from your extension delegate through `[WKExtension sharedExtension].rootInterfaceController`

Comment: Hi dan, that's great. Thanks very much. Can I also ask what would be the best code to then active a UIbutton action on that pushed controller all from the app delegate

Comment: You can use a delegate pattern. In short:: you have a delegate variable in your extension and call it. It is implemented by the controller where you want to push from. The controller where you want to push from sets extension.myDelegate = self.

Comment: @GerdCastan that sounds perfect. Do you know were I can find some sample code. In new to coding with my main language being swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As @dan has pointed out in the comments, you can get a reference to your root controller using `[WKExtension sharedExtension].rootInterfaceController`. From there you can use `pushControllerWithName:context:` to push a controller.

Comment: Swift3 update: `WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController?`

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the line below to get the root controller worked for me using Swift.

```
rootInterfaceController?.pushController(withName: "MapController", context: path)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could inherit `WKInterfaceController` and store the current controller in somewhere.

```
class BaseInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    ...

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        // store current controller with some weak reference
        XXXManager.shareInstance().currentController = self
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()

        if XXXManager.shareInstance().currentController == self {
            XXXManager.shareInstance().currentController = nil
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that. I tried to inherit the View controller but as the appDelegate (where i want to action the code) is NSObject it doesn't let me do it with a comment multiple inheritances from UIResponder and UIViewController error. I wonder if the delegate method Gerd mentioned above may be the best way but i'm struggling being new to coding. does anyone know were i could find some example swift code on how to do this? thanks in advance for helping a newbie :)